# Google Play internal testing requires tester to "verify your age" to download

Tags: android, google-play

We have created a new app on Google Play. We have created an "internal testing" test track. We have created a release and uploaded an app bundle. We have added a tester (me). I then go via the opt-in link to install the app but I am presented with a screen saying "Verify you age to continue".

The result is that I can not download the internal test track app without first going through the "verify your age" steps which I most specifically do not want to do - the account is used for testing purposes only.

The app name is presented as the application id (reverse DNS) and the text "unreviewed".

Is there a way to get the app in the hands of testers without "verify your age" steps? I have never seen this before and have used this account to test lots of our apps previously.

Answer (score 0):

From my tests it looks that it is connected with using Google Workspace account as tester, when I use regular gmail account it does not show age verification.
So my guess is, Google turned by default some option on Workspace, but question is  where is this option?

Comment: Seems like a likely explanation! Do you have a credit card assigned to your regular gmail account, e.g. to buy apps on Play Store?

Comment: Tested more ... on other gmail accounts there is no age verification showing, what connects them is they had birthdate provided in Personal settings, no bank cards added. On other hand Workspace account has bank cards added but it shows age verification, but it did not have added birth date in settings. So I added on two Workspace accounts birthdate, but age verifiy still shows. Clearing Google Play cache did not work ...

Comment: @NicolaiHenriksen Hi Nocolai. I am struggling with exactly the same problem. Please, did you solve it?

Comment: Same here, also as Workspace user. When I killed the app halfway the verification process and retried the installation, it continued without prompting for the age verification.